# Дополнительное окно при нажатии в WinFoms

Tags: c#, winforms

коллеги.Поставил задачу сделать стратегию в WinForms,хотел бы спросить у вас,как реализовать возможность при нажатии на панель создавать второе окно,к примеру для экономических действий,но это уже другое,главное,как же ее при нажатии добавить,заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если вы хотите нормального интерфейса и понятного кода, изучайте WPF и шаблон программирования MVVM, и не забудьте про основы ООП. Сейчас вы спрашиваете о том, что можно [нагуглить](https://yandex.ru/search/smart/?lr=2&text=C%23+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE+Winforms) за 30 секунд, это не хорошо. Начните хотя-бы с [этого](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ)

Comment: `сделать стратегию в WinForms` если пишете игру, почему бы её не написатьна чем то, что предназначено для игр (unity, например) или хотя бы на чем то, что имеет большую поддержку для рисования (wpf)?